# Django error: Invalid block tag on line 28: 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm stuck on this error I am a new user of Django I am following the steps correctly and learning through YT.

[When I run python manage.py runserver the HTML shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5boxt.png)

My index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header>
    CRUD Operation with PostgreSQL
</header>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>How to create CURD Ops with PostgreSQL</h1>
        <h3>Learning Django and CURD</h3>
        <hr/>
        <table border = "1">
            <tr>
                <th>Employee Id</th>
                <th>Employee Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Occupation</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
            {% for results in data% }
            <tr>
                <td>{{result.id}}</td>
                <td>{{result.name}}</td>
                <td>{{result.email}}</td>
                <td>{{result.occupation}}</td>
                <td>{{result.salary}}</td>
                <td>{{result.gender}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
```

I tried to change endfor to endblock nothing works. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I think this is just a typo. I believe `data% }` needs to be `data %}`.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I would encourage you to try again because I can reproduce your error  by making a similar typo in a template. Make sure you're restarting the server after (or ensuring that hot-reloading is running).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code here:

```
{% for results in data% }
<tr>
    <td>{{result.id}}</td>
    <td>{{result.name}}</td>
    <td>{{result.email}}</td>
    <td>{{result.occupation}}</td>
    <td>{{result.salary}}</td>
    <td>{{result.gender}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

You need to change `{% for results in data% }` to `{% for result in data %}`. Be careful, where you put whitespaces and look at plural `results` in for loop, when you actually uses singular `result` inside it.